# Hide Java output in HTML file

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I write this code in `scala.html` to show the MySQL data in an `HTML` table:

```
@for(a <- 1 to rowNum){
    @rs.next()
<tr>
  <td>@rs.getString("building_id")</td>
  <td>@rs.getString("building_name")</td>
  <td>@rs.getString("building_type")</td>
  <td>@rs.getString("address")</td>
</tr>
```

It gives the following result:

```
true true true true true true true true true true
id  name    type    address
1   The Floravale   condo   Westwood Avenue
2   building2   condo   Jurong West Street 21
3   building3   hdb Jurong West Street 31
4   building4   hdb Jurong West Street 81
5   building5   hdb Jurong West Street 61
6   building6   hdb Jurong West Street 81
7   building7   hdb Kang Ching Road
8   building8   hdb Kang Ching Road
9   building9   hdb Boon Lay Drive
10  building10  hdb Boon Lay Place
```

How can I hide the `true` as the output of `@rs.next()`?
Or are there other ways to display data? Thanks!

Comment: Why is this marked to close? I assume @rs.next() returns true, so the question is how to assign the result of @rs.next() to a var? - Also I would expect to see `while(@rs.next())`

Comment: How do you create your `@rs`? Can't you use `@for(a <- rs)` ? Do you really use Play. 2.0.0 ? Which language is basic in your case? what ORM do you use? I didn't click for closing, but I'm gonna to if you won't fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it is probably that `true` is being returned, and therefore appearing as a result. A more typical usage would be to collect your rows in a List passed to the view, often in it's own case class (say `Building`), then use a map:

```
@buildings.map { building =>
  <td>building.id</td>
  <td>building.name</td>
  ...
}
```